# How to change login screen background (Gnome 43, debian 12)

Tags: debian, gdm3

I changed from Windows to Linux (Debian 12) after 10yrs. I'm still a beginner but I'm just loving the learning processing.

- This is my specs:
  [image]

**My question**

- When I shutdown and boot up my system the login screen, the background is solid black:
  [image]
- But after logging in, the login screen applies transparency effects like this:
  [image]

Can we make transparency effect as default, and if so, how?

Comment: Yeah, you could ask that here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues

Comment: Are you saying this issue @ArtemS.Tashkinov

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've added the missing info. any suggestions would be great